# Jenkins and AWS SAM: withAWS unable to assume role

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, cicd, identity-management

I'm using the auto-generated hello world jenkinsfile built by the SAM CLI:

```
 steps {
        sh 'sam build --template ${SAM_TEMPLATE}'
        withAWS(
            credentials: env.PIPELINE_USER_CREDENTIAL_ID,
            region: env.TESTING_REGION,
            role: env.TESTING_PIPELINE_EXECUTION_ROLE,
            roleSessionName: 'deploying-feature') {
          sh '''
            sam deploy --stack-name $(echo ${BRANCH_NAME} | tr -cd '[a-zA-Z0-9-]') \
              --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM \
              --region ${TESTING_REGION} \
              --s3-bucket ${TESTING_ARTIFACTS_BUCKET} \
              --no-fail-on-empty-changeset \
              --role-arn ${TESTING_CLOUDFORMATION_EXECUTION_ROLE}
          '''
        }
      }
    }
```

1. PIPELINE_USER_CREDENTIAL_ID is a username+password jenkins credential with my iam user access key + secret key. The IAM user has permissions to assume the IAM role.
2. TESTING_PIPELINE_EXECUTION_ROLE is an IAM role which has the iam user above as the trusted entity, and has adminaccess policy attached.

The sam deploy command fails with:

```
File with same data already exists at a6dc4a9f480ec00ce6c24c290c1e5099.template, skipping upload
Error: Failed to create changeset for the stack: feature-001, An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Role arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/myrole is invalid or cannot be assumed
```

I'm trying to think of why this role can't be assumed. My jenkins access key credentials are correct, my role allows that user to assume it, and has admin access policy so should be able to do anything in cloudformation.

My Jenkins is running on ec2, do I need to do anything with the instance profile? Or should the trust policy for my role be something else when using the withAWS plugin?

Answer (score 0):

FIX: SAM requires 2 IAM roles, one for the jenkins pipeline and one for cloudformation:

```
TESTING_PIPELINE_EXECUTION_ROLE
TESTING_CLOUDFORMATION_EXECUTION_ROLE
```

I had both of those set to the same IAM role. Fix is to either create 2 separate IAM roles, or use the same env var for role and --role-arn.

I think is issue was the role was trying to assume itself and getting denied.